# Is it possible to customize ServiceNow for Slack?

Tags: slack, servicenow

Is it possible to customize [ServiceNow for Slack](https://slack.com/blog/productivity/servicenow-for-slack)? Can I view the code behind "Create an Incident"? Can I change the behavior? For example, can I cause it to set `contact_type` to "Slack"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, **ServiceNow for Slack** in not customizable for now.
The best customization you can achieve is using **`slack workflows`**.

 Check **Customize incident workflows** in the same [link](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/blog/productivity/servicenow-for-slack)

> Teams can create workflows to:
>
> - Build a custom form with any ServiceNow field to capture a ServiceNow
>   Incident in Slack
> - Automatically create incident channels
> - Send specific users messages in Slack when an incident is created from a
>   workflow
> - Leverage steps from other apps to trigger a ServiceNow
>   Incident in response to an event in Slack

Limitation of workflows is that you can only associate it with a single channel.